# Doing an Apache redirect with unchanged URL

Tags: apache, apache2

I would like to make a redirect with unchanged URL. I have tried the configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.localhost
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://www.example.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

but it doesn't work as I get a message in the browser saying "The page isn't redirecting properly". Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a rewrite with the proxy flag P:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.localhost
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```